# Is there anyway to find owner of an orphaned object on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've been trying to figure out how to find what is retaining this object.  But nothing seems to be referencing it anymore, so how is it still retained? It shows up as a leak, in both instruments and the memory debugger.

Is it possible that something isn't symbolicated for the memory debugger to figure out whats retaining this? What would cause an orphaned object like this?

Notes: I am using realm, but this object is not associated with Realm directly. (Just using the RLM prefix for this particular object).
[image: Notice the lone object.]

Comment: Maybe your object is retaining _itself_ (most commonly by a closure propety that references `self` strongly)?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your object is retaining itself. This readily happen when using closures. Make sure to explicitly annotate your self as weak in your closures like this:

```
someFunc() { [weak self] in
    // some code
    self?.propertyOnSelf
}
```

Comment: This would be my first instinct as well, but no its a fairly simple object that doesn't even have a closure property. See my answer below, its quite bizarre.

Answer (score -1):

This was a tough one, but I think I found the answer. So I have a generic array of AnyObjects ([AnyObject]) and I "know" that these are Hashable values. I was under the conception that I could do:
 `objects as! AnyHashable`

This compiles and appears to work, but this actually causes a memory leak! I'm assuming something is happening internal here within Swift to cause this. Maybe I can put this in a confined file to prove that this leaks.  Nothing leaks if I pass each Hashable value to AnyHashable(object).

Unfortunately I still need to find a way to coerce my generic AnyObject values to be Hashable.